# Javascript callbacks within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I'm writing a Javascript app that is getting an HTML document via AJAX, then needs to process it to attach event listeners (specifically, Bootstrap popovers) to the elements inside it.  I'm having difficulty attaching the listeners, and I believe it's a scope issue.  Here's the relevant code:

```
var App = function(site){

  this.load = function(data, func){
    $('div.ajax').html(data);
    func();
  }

  this.dispatch = function(data){

    if(data.indexOf('from_server') !== -1){
      this.load(data, this.process);
      console.log('Loaded view from Matisse.');
      return true;
    }

  }

  this.process = function(){
    this.popovers('from_server');
  }

  this.popovers = function(el){
    var that = this;
    $('img.artwork.gallery', el).each(function(){
       $(this).popover({ trigger: 'hover', content: that.popoverPopulate(this) });
    });
  }

  this.popoverPopulate = function(el){
    return $(el).next('div.popover_content').html();
  }
}

var APP = new App();

$.ajax({blah: blah, success: function(data){ APP.dispatch(data); }});

...
```

The problem (I think) is the `func()` call in `this.load`.  If I pass it `this.process()`, then it scopes the 'this' to the window, and there's an error.  If I pass `this.process`, it's a lambda that's created and it still fails.  If I call `this.func()` the same problem occurs.

How do I either a) keep the scope within the App object with the callback, or b) reorganize this mess to call the handler after load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine you want to use the `var that=this` scoping trick on all of the methods:

```
var App = function(site){

  var that = this;

  this.load = function(data, func){
    $('div.ajax').html(data);
    func();
  }

  this.dispatch = function(data){

    if(data.indexOf('from_server') !== -1){
      that.load(data, that.process);
      console.log('Loaded view from Matisse.');
      return true;
    }

  }

  this.process = function(){
    that.popovers('from_server');
  }

  this.popovers = function(el){
    $('img.artwork.gallery', el).each(function(){
       $(that).popover({ trigger: 'hover', content: that.popoverPopulate(this) });
    });
  }

  this.popoverPopulate = function(el){
    return $(el).next('div.popover_content').html();
  }
}
```

Comment: Accepted because it came in first, but kudos to Ilia as well.  I'd already done this by the time the answer came in, but thank you.  The listeners still aren't attaching, but I think that's an issue with Bootstrap, not my Javascript.

Comment: Ah, yeah - I haven't used bootstrap, so I'm not familiar with its issues. Good luck! (also, I'll second the kudos @Ilia - two minutes ain't nothing.)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
var App = function(site){
    var self = this; //-<!!!

    this.load = function(data, func){

    ...

    this.dispatch = function(data){
        if(data.indexOf('from_server') !== -1){
            self.load(data, self.process);
    ...
```

Comment: hahahaha, I really like your "pay attention to this" comment! That's excellent. 

Also, on that last line (before the "...") you probably want to use `self` instead of `this` on the method call as well as the reference you're passing in, no? Or will `this` still be the object and not `window` at that point?

Answer (score 1):

this refers to the context in which it is used at the moment. So when you do `this.process` it's going to target the window. If you do `App.load(data, App.process)` then it'll target the process function within the `App` object.